# Combine across groups within variable

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable

I need to create all combinations across groups in a dataframe.

Let's say I start with:

```
df <- tibble(
 j = c("x", "x", "y", "y", "z", "z"),
 k = c(100, 300, 20, 60, 40, 35),
 ind = c(0 ,0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
)
```

What I need is something like this:

```
want <- tibble(
 j_k = c("100_20","100_60","300_20","300_60")
)
```

I've reviewed similar questions that point to things like expand() and combn(). The problem is most posts are about creating all combinations across variables, whereas I need combinations across groups within variables, with the option to reject based on an indicator (`ind` in my example), and with control over the delimiter between the combined values.

Okay to change data shape to make this easier.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `expand.grid` and `split` in base R:

```r
df_new <- with(df[df$ind == 0, ], expand.grid(split(k, j)))
do.call(paste, c(df_new, sep = "_"))
#[1] "100_20" "300_20" "100_60" "300_60"
```